# Responsive, transparent CSS image caption with graceful degradation?

Tags: image, html, css, responsive-design, graceful-degradation

What is the proper way to create responsive, transparent CSS captions over images — with graceful degradation in older browsers?

I am trying to achieve:

- Centered vertical column of images
- Images are equal heights and widths
- Each image has a caption which should be centered
- Caption should have a see-through background
- Would be nice if the background became black in older browsers that don't support transparency

If you take a look at [this Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/XjthT/3/), there's clearly a lot wrong with it.

The basic premise for HTML5 is:

```
<section>
    <figure>
        <img src="1.jpg">
        <figcaption>Caption 1</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
        <img src="2.jpg">
        <figcaption>Caption 2</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
        <img src="3.jpg">
        <figcaption>Caption 3</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

But the [CSS3 code](http://jsfiddle.net/Baumr/XjthT/3/) is where we get some problems. Is it the right approach even? I got it to work with some fine-tuning (not included), but the fine-tuning doesn't seem to make semantic sense to me anyway.

For example, this is the result:

[image]

I have a feeling the CSS is wrong on many levels (pun intended).

Comment: Sorry for being off-topic, but I don't recognize the `<section>` and `<figure>` tags. Could you briefly explain them please?

Comment: No problem. This will cover `<figure>` better than I can: http://html5doctor.com/the-figure-figcaption-elements/ and same goes for `<section>` with this: http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element/

Comment: Thanks, awesome site. Didnt know about until now, appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help! It's a good one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I modified your CSS slightly. The main changes were adding `position: relative;` to the parent element and `position: absolute;` to the caption.

**CSS**:

```
section {
    overflow: auto;
}

section figure {
    float: left;
    clear: both;

    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;

    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 15px;
}

section figure img {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

section figure figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff; 
    padding: 10px;
}


section {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    background: #ccc;

}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XjthT/6/**

Comment: Just have to note that rgba(0,0,0,0.7) is CSS3 property and will not work in IE8 and previous versions

Comment: **A)** Thanks Reflective! Much appreciated. How will the transparency render in IE8? How can I make it degrade to being black?

Comment: **B)** Thanks again for the updated CSS, it works! Though unfortunately it isn't responsive. My example is probably confusing, but the images would be larger, and should size-down. How would the `position: absolute` and `relative` you used fare for responsive? Are they better to use instead of a negative `margin-top` property? (It also didn't center-align even though you included `margin: 0 auto;` which is strange.) Also, why the `overflow: auto` property?

Comment: In IE8 and older you can use a gradient filter to get a semitransparent background `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#bb000000, endColorstr=#bb000000);`. If you want responsive images, then you should probably set their width in % with respect to their parent http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/XjthT/15/ If you apply `position: absolute` on an element, then the `top`/`right`/`bottom`/`width` values you apply on it are with respect to its first ancestor having `position: relative`. I don't understand why you say it didn't center-align, looks center-aligned to me...

Comment: Resize in order to see it's responsive http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/XjthT/15/embedded/result/

Comment: @Ana, thanks for your reply! Ah, I meant that the `figures` in the `section` didn't center-align to the page — tried it in WebKit/FF... Also, regarding the absolute and relative `position` — is it better to use that, instead of `margin:-20px` for example? Anyway, thank you for the responsive changes and the transparency solutions! **Perfect!** Do you see any other potential bugs or browser incompatibilities in the code as is? Thanks again!

Comment: Weird, I see them center-aligned in both Chrome & FF on Win 7 :-?? This example http://dabblet.com/gist/3971071 shows why absolutely positioning the `figcaption` would be better than using negative `margin` (the `white` `outline` is the one around the `img` and the `yellow` one is around the `figcaption`). The only other thing I would change would be to use dimensions in `em` instead of using them in `px` (that has to do with how things scale on zoom - see http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/ ).

Comment: The *negative margin method* fixes the `top` of the `figcaption` box with respect to the `bottom` of its preceding sibling (the `img`). On smaller screens, the `figcaption` text spans more lines and looks like it's spilling out of the image. The *absolute positioning method* fixes the `bottom` of the `figcaption` box to the `bottom` of its parent (the `figure`). When the text of the `figcaption` spans more lines, it's the `top` that goes up automatically

Comment: **Thank you!** Great example, you got me 100% convinced absolute positioning is best. On that note, now you even got me interested in using `%` instead of `em`... Also, about the `center-align` did you try making the window bigger? That's when it is no longer centered for me.

Comment: Ana, I tried the deCSS3 script (http://davatron5000.github.com/deCSS3/) on your earlier example (http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/XjthT/15/embedded/result/) via a copy of your implementation on my site, it takes away the black background of the captions completely — leaves nothing. Any ideas why? Shouldn't it simply revert to the `background:black` property?